# Spring Data JPA - Spring is ignoring the almost all the field annotations

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

**Disclaimer:** It's hardly the first time I used JPA and Spring together, I've never observed this behaviour before.

The gist of the issue is as follows: The Spring managed JPA layer is apparently ignoring the vast majority of field/property annotations when mapping entities.
I'm using exclusively the Spring data jpa stuff here, from the spring boot starter 2.7.7.

Do note that I'm aware of the various Physical/implicit strategy things. They are PART of the issue but not THE issue.

Short example to explain:

```java
@Entity // This works! Remove it and it's not detected
@Table(name = "PERSON") // This also works, remove it and the generated SQL goes against PERSONENTITY
public class PersonEntity extends IdEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

//  @Column(name = "NAME") <- It's commented but it's still in the generated SQL queries
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "CAMEL_CASED_FIELD") // In this case the PHYSICAL naming strategy should apply, however it's ignored and it falls back to the implicit one, meaning it's ignoring this annotation.
    private String camelCasedField;

    @Column(name = "GENERATED", insertable=false, updatable=false) // Gets ignored, insert/update statements include the field
    private String generated;

    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient // Gets ignored, insert/update statements include the field
    private String field1;

    @javax.persistence.Transient // Gets ignored, insert/update statements include the field
    private String field2;

    @ReadOnlyProperty // Gets ignored, insert/update statements include the field
    private String field3;

    @Immutable // Gets ignored, insert/update statements include the field
    private String field4;

// <cut for brevity, just getters and setters>
```

Now, the column naming issue I can live with, however I NEED at the very least the "insertable/updatable" statements to be correctly taken into account as it's a database generate column and inserts WILL generate errors and rollbacks.

The configuration is ALL Spring based, no persistence.xml (which I've also tried, but to no avail).

The relevant bit:

```java
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory (
        DataSource dataSource,
        MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl,
        CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl
    ) {
        Map<String, Object> jpaPropertiesMap = new java.util.HashMap<>(jpaProperties.getProperties());
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.PHYSICAL_NAMING_STRATEGY, PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl.class.getName());
        // Uncommenting this line will map column names correctly but only by accident
        // Besides,with the @Column(name = "XX") annotation it should use the PHYSICAL strategy.
//        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.IMPLICIT_NAMING_STRATEGY, ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl.class.getName());
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.SCHEMA);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.integrator_provider", MetadataExtractorIntegrator.PROVIDER);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.foo.bar.api.model");
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("my-unit");
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaPropertiesMap);
        return em;
    }
```

I have tried literally any combination of configurations I can think of (like using the Persistence Provider instead of using the Adapter) but the results always fall exactly in two camps:

1. The configuration just isn't valid and the application doesn't start at all
2. The configuration is valid but gives me the exact same results as stated above.

I tried to see if there's some conflicting items in the pom.xml but there's only spring data that's relevant.

Additionally, this configuration was taken almost verbatim from another project (different versions and far more complex but still Spring Boot) and there it worked as expected.

I'm at wits' end.

Comment: Turn on logging for Hibernate and it might tell you the annotations it is picking up and using - and errors/reasons for not picking up others. I'd guess you have too much going on that is overlapping. Pick JPA and remove the other annotations, and simplify things until they work (like removing naming strategies and multitenent options); fix or get a handle on one issue at a time.

Comment: I tried all of the above, generally speaking the only annotations I'm using are the javax.persistence ones, mainly \@Entity, \@Table and \@Column. The ones above are just examples of the attempts I tried. The naming strategies also were all disabled at some point. The multi tenant strategy has no impact here.

Comment: Create the minimal test case and show that then, not the attempted workarounds. I'm skeptical the other settings aren't contributing, and commonly other class files get in the way on the class path, so we cannot tell what you really have and what is not working or that there aren't other version of your class hidden in the class path somewhere. Even remove the naming strategies - you are asking about update/insert settings, not column names right? Even something as trivial as an annotation found on a property might cause your annotations on fields to be ignored.